# Remove the relationship created when performing a baseless merge?

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

Recently did a baseless merge, now when merging from the branch that was merged into, the branch that was baselessly merged from is the default branch to merge to in the UI. Is there anyway to remove this association between the two branches that were merged baseless-ly?

Comment: My understanding is that there isn't a default branch. The merge drop down is sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: Is there a way to disassociate the relationship created between two branches after the have been merged baselessly?

Comment: I'm afraid not, see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788688/remove-a-branching-relationship-in-tfs-2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, once you have created the relationship there is no way to remove that relationship.

See: [Remove a Branching Relationship in TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788688/remove-a-branching-relationship-in-tfs-2010)