# Remove branch relationship in TFS

Tags: tfs, branch, branching-and-merging

I moved a branch of my mainline into an "Archive" folder and selected "Convert to folder", but when I go to merge my mainline I still see the archived folder as a selectable target. How do I remove the relationship between the two branches so I no longer see it in the merge dialog?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a Branching Relationship in TFS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788688/remove-a-branching-relationship-in-tfs-2010)

Comment: I'm using TFS 2012 and the accepted answer there talks about creating a check-in policy. How could that possibly solve my issue?

Comment: There is no solution to your issue, you cannot remove a branching relationship in TFS. The workaround is to create a checkin policy preventing accidental merges to a branch that is no longer required. For your specific scenario you could just delete the branch rather than moving it. You can always undelete it later if you need to access code. Moving branches is not a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach is to 'delete' the branch. This will not remove the history and will only hide the branch from the timeline. You can use the "View deleted items" option in the Source Control settings to see the branch and you can always Undelete it.