# How do I inject a branch between two branches in TFS 2012

Tags: branch, branching-and-merging

I currently have two branches setup

Main -> Dev

I want to inject a Test branch in-between those two branches.

I was originally going to branch from Main to Test then perform a baseless merge between Dev and Test then reparent Dev to Test until I read this:

[Remove a Branching Relationship in TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788688/remove-a-branching-relationship-in-tfs-2010)

Since there is no way to remove the relationship between dev and main I could see this being a problem in the future.

My next thought is to branch from Main to Trunk.
Then reparent main to trunk.

So now I will have

Dev -> Main -> Trunk

Then rename Main to Test

So I will end up with

Dev -> Test -> Trunk

I am concerned about renaming Main and messing up the history.  Also, if as a final step I renamed Trunk to Main, would that cause problems since I am renaming it to a branch that previously existed?

If anyone has thoughts on how to accomplish what I am looking for I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options, each with their own issues:

1. Rename $/Project/dev to $/project/test, branch $/project/test to $/Project/Develop (needs to get a new name, otherwise the old branch relation will be revived)
2. Create a new branch for $/project/test from $/project/main. destroy $/project/dev. create a branch from $/project/test to $/project/dev. (history on dev is lost)
3. Branch $/project/main to $/project/test, reparent $/project/dev, merge test -> dev. (the branch relation is succesfully created, but the relation persists between dev and main).

Comment: When Dev and Main are the same, you can break the branch relationship (convert to folder), branch main to test and then reparent the original dev branch to test.

Comment: @Matt We have active feature branches being developed with dev as the parent.  I am trying not to create too much upheaval in the process.

Comment: @jessehouwing Maybe I am missing something... if you convert to a folder and then convert back to a branch, the branch relationship still exists.  Not sure how that helps.

Comment: It's the closest you can get. You can never delete the branch relation without destroying the whole folder in source control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425.aspx

Comment: I am going to go with what I have now and rename main... I will lose the history in main but that history is mostly merges from dev.  The actual change history exists in dev (for the most part).